# Ignore No Subdomain In htaccess RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've got htaccess set up that redirects all subdomains except www to https. However I'd also like it to ignore http://domain.com - currently it redirects to https://domain.com which is no good for what I'm doing.

Any idea what the rewrite condition is for that?

I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://domain.com [NC]
```

But neither of those work.

Here's what I'm using at the minute.

```
# Redirect subdomains to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you need to escape the dot in `domain.com`, so `domain\.com`.

```
# Redirect subdomains to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You used a 301 (permanent) and not a 302, so you may have your browser not even trying to send requests to the http domain until you close. You should use 302 while testing and put the 301 only wen it's ok.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - the 302 hadn't occurred to me. The http://domain.com is still redirecting to https though. I'm a bit stumped on this one.

Comment: @logic-unit: did you close your browser before testing? after that you can add debug by adding RewriteLogLevel 9 and RewriteLog /tmp/rewrite.log in your Virtualhost. Then check what happended in the file /tmp/rewrite.log.

Comment: I tried it in a different browser, still no dice. Thanks for the log file tip, I'll give that a try now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, that looked good, but it still redirects to https. I must be missing something.

Comment: as regilero said: try it with another browser because of the 301 redirection, I guess your browser cached this redirect.